# Read JSON objects with Matlab

Tags: json, matlab, object

I want to read from a json file with Matlab and store everything in "data" as objects. After import, I need to iterate through all and extract specific values, if it's available in the object.

**JSON (source):**

```
{
    "eid": 44000, 
    "dpm_id": {
        "dpm": "fm", 
        "pwr": "main"
    }, 
    "fpga_id": 3189637128, 
    "fpga_ver": 3104379702, 
    "boot_id": 0, 
    "pbs_ver": "PBS 2012-05-07 16:41"
}
{
    "sid": 1, 
    "hk1": {
        "bela_mode": "pbs_mode", 
        "pbs_version": "version 1.3", 
        "scet": "2038-01-19T03:14:08", 
        "ref_time": "0:00:00", 
        "tc_received": 2, 
        "tc_exec": 2, 
        "tc_err_ack": 0, 
        "tc_err_exec": 1, 
        "tm_total": 1, 
        "tm_sent": 1, 
        "tm_dropped": 0,
        ....
```

**Matlab (import, [according to this website, resp. Class](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42236-parse-json-text/content/example/html/usage.html)):**

```
fname = 'FileName.json';
fid = fopen(fname);
raw = fread(fid,inf);
str = char(raw');
fclose(fid);

data = JSON.parse(str)
```

**Problem/Question:**

As you see, Matlab only reads the content of the first brackets/field. How can I import ALL brackets/fields, even if I don't know how many there are?

```
data = 

         eid: 44000
      dpm_id: [1x1 struct]
     fpga_id: 3.1896e+09
    fpga_ver: 3.1044e+09
     boot_id: 0
     pbs_ver: 'PBS 2012-05-07 16:41'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look here: http://iso2mesh.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/index.cgi?jsonlab
Source here: https://github.com/fangq/jsonlab

Comment: Some possibilities to parse json: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/json-matlab-integration

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to read a json file, which is not valid. I recommend to use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) for a quick verification.

Your json looks like

```
{
    "skipped":"A"    
}
{
    "skipped":"B"
}
```

That is not a valid syntax, because it describes two objects. After the first `}` the parser expects the end of file because a json file contains one object.

Possible fixes are:

```
[
    {
        "skipped": "A"
    },
    {
        "skipped": "B"
    }
]
```

or

```
{
    "aa": {
        "skipped": "A"
    },
    "bb": {
        "skipped": "B"
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. One has to care about this syntax even with the webread function.

Answer (score 4):

If your file is accessible *via* `http` or `https`, you can use the `webread` function from the `Data Import and Export` toolbox. It automatically converts JSON files to Matlab structures.

There is a `decodeJSON` function in the toolbox (`MATLABROOT/toolbox/matlab/external/interfaces/webservices/restful/private/decodeJSON.m`), but the help clearly states that:

```
% FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY -- This function is intentionally undocumented
%   and is intended for use only within the scope of functions and classes
%   in toolbox/matlab/external/interfaces/webservices/restful. Its behavior
%   may change, or the class itself may be removed in a future release.
```

Nevertheless you can get inspiration in the content to build your own solution. It's a pity that the Mathworks didn't made this program available outside the toolbox.

Best

Answer (score 3):

You could try parsing using another json library, such as [this one on file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20565-json-parser).

Alternatively you could try some of the methods listed on [this site](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/json-matlab-integration), such as using matlab's Java and .NET integration and loading with one of their json libraries.

As a third alternative, since the method you have shown above will happily load the first object in the string, you could always do some manual pre-parsing of the string into a cell array of strings containing a single object each, and then parse those.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read whole JSON files into MATLAB, and have a C++11 compiler, you can use the very fast [json_read](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/59166-json-read) mex function.