# Parsing with regexp in Matlab when a variable has underscores

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a cell array of characters `rawDividends` of the following form:

```
...  
\"_date\":\"1462455000\",\"_amount\":\"0.57\",\"_amount_currency\":\"USD\",\"_payable_date\":\"1463059800\"
...
```

I try to parse the values using the following expressions:

```
dates = regexp(rawDividends, '(?<="_date\\":\\")[0-9.]*?(?=\\)', 'match', 'once');
amounts = regexp(rawDividends, '(?<=amount\\":\\")[0-9.]*?(?=\\)', 'match', 'once');

dcurrency = regexp(rawDividends, '(?<=_amount_currency\\":\\")[0-9.]*?(?=\\)', 'match', 'once');
dpayabledate = regexp(rawDividends, '(?<=_payable_date\\":\\")[0-9.]*?(?=\\)', 'match', 'once');
```

All work fine except for _amount_currency. I suspect it is because of the _amount that is also before. How can this be solved?

Comment: See [Read JSON objects with Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787245/read-json-objects-with-matlab). Besides, how can you match `USD` with `[0-9.]` pattern? There is no point in using those lookaheads: use greedy quantifiers and remove all of the lookaheads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because your regex is looking for `[0-9.]*` rather than `[A-Z]*`

```
dcurrency = regexp(rawDividends, '(?<=_amount_currency\\":\\")[A-Z]*?(?=\\)', 'match', 'once');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may benefit from extractBetween which was introduced in 16b

```
dates = extractBetween(rawDividends,'_date\":\"','\');
amounts = extractBetween(rawDividends,'_amount\":\"','\');
```

It may be faster. It's definitely a bit easier than regexp.

EDIT: Did some performance analysis because I was curious...

```
function profFunc

    rawDividends = '\"_date\":\"1462455000\",\"_amount\":\"0.57\",\"_amount_currency\":\"USD\",\"_payable_date\":\"1463059800\"';
    rawDividends = repmat({rawDividends},1000,1);

    n = 1E3;

    tic
    for i = 1:n
       dates = regexp(rawDividends, '(?<="_date\\":\\")[0-9.]*?(?=\\)', 'match', 'once'); 
    end
    toc

    tic
    for i = 1:n
        dates = extractBetween(rawDividends,'"_date\":\"','\');
    end
    toc

    rawDividends = string(rawDividends);

    tic
    for i = 1:n
        dates = extractBetween(rawDividends,'"_date\":\"','\');
    end
    toc

end

>> profFunc
Elapsed time is 1.533854 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.710215 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.326965 seconds.
```

So extractBetween on a cellstr is ~2x faster than regexp on a cellstr and extractBetween on a string is ~5x faster than regexp on a cellstr.

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks